# Unexpected behavior with window focus events

Tags: java, swing, window, focus, awt

I'm creating an application with `Swing`, and I've got a problem. I want to handle the `focusLost()` and `focusGained()` events, but I think my code is buggy.

I've got the following, test code:

```
addWindowFocusListener(new WindowFocusListener() {
    @Override
    public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Lost!");
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Gained!");
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
});
```

And, when I **activate** the window, it seems that app handles 2 events **at once**:

```
Gained!
java.awt.event.WindowEvent[WINDOW_GAINED_FOCUS,opposite=null,oldState=0,newState=0] on frame0
Lost!
java.awt.event.WindowEvent[WINDOW_LOST_FOCUS,opposite=null,oldState=0,newState=0] on frame0
```

And, when I deactivate the window, the program prints nothing.

There's also more interesting thing. When I open a new `JFrame` that belongs to my app, the event system **works properly**, even when I close this second `Window`.

I just don't know why it is happening. Please help.

System specs:

- **OS**: Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64
- **JVM**: OpenJDK 7

```
m4tx@m4tx-EP35-DS4:~$ java -version
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
java version "1.7.0_03"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.1.1pre) (7~u3-2.1.1~pre1-1ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Can you post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem (i.e. something that can be run as is)?

Comment: Please post the code. I undone the down vote by giving you an up vote, because of my policy about questions.

Comment: At this moment I can't... I wrote simple example for myself, but there's everything ok. An app, where I have this problem is a bit big app, so I can't upload the code there. I think the problem may be caused by jMonkeyEngine (lwjgl) canvas. If I would be able to write SSCCE, I would write it...

Comment: Yeah, I deleted the jME canvas and it works ok. I'll write a example code as fast as I can.

Comment: It sounds like you're mixing AWT and Swing.

Comment: It's possible that you have the same listener attached twice

Comment: No. Notice that there're 2 events (gained and lost), when window gains focus, and no events when window losts focus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I can't see much wrong with your code; so I put together a quick demo, and it seems to be working fine:

```
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowFocusListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class WindowEventDemo extends JFrame implements WindowFocusListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new WindowEventDemo("Window Event Demo").setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public WindowEventDemo(String name) {
        super(name);
        addWindowFocusListener(this);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300, 300);
    }

    @Override
    public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("WindowFocusListener method called: windowGainedFocus.");
    }

    @Override
    public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("WindowFocusListener method called: windowLostFocus.");
    }
}
```

On start up it prints:

> WindowFocusListener method called: windowGainedFocus.

and when the window is **minimized**, or the **mouse is clicked somewhere else on screen** besides the `JFrame` is prints:

> WindowFocusListener method called: windowLostFocus.